# FireAlarm: detecting low-quality questions with machine learning

Tags: app, questions, chatbot

<sup>There are two versions of FireAlarm.  [One version](//github.com/SOBotics/FireAlarm/tree/c) is written in C, and [the other](//github.com/SOBotics/FireAlarm) is written in Swift.  This post is about the Swift version.</sup>

---

FireAlarm is a chatbot [Ashish Ahuja](////stackoverflow.com/users/4688119/ashish-ahuja) and I have been working on.  It attempts to detect low-quality questions using a [naive Bayes](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) filter.

[image: A sample report.]

All reports can be seen on FireAlarm's web dashboard, [Bonfire](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/) ([StackApps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/7844/bonfire-dashboard-for-firealarm-detecting-low-quality-questions)).

## How accurate is it?

Each question is assigned a score by the machine learning filter, and a lower score means the question is more likely to be bad.  Different chat rooms have different thresholds; in [SOCVR](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) the threshold is 35, in [SOBotics](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) it's 45, and in [FireAlarm Development](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123602/firealarm-development) it's whatever we want it to be at the moment.

At a threshold of 35, since the bot started running in SOCVR on February 8:

- 12% of reported posts have close votes but aren't closed or deleted,
- 13.98% are closed but not deleted, and
- 40.7% are deleted,

which adds up to 66.7%.  That's pretty impressive, considering only about 9% of questions from that time period are closed.  (I wasn't able to get statistics on deleted posts or posts with close votes.)

- 5.8% of non-deleted reported posts have a positive score
- 31.5% of non-deleted reported posts have a negative score
- 78.4% of all reported posts have a negative score, have close votes, are closed, or are deleted.

## Where does it run?

FireAlarm is currently running in [SOBotics](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), [SO Close Vote Reviewers](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and of course the [FireAlarm Development](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123602/firealarm-development) room.  Enter a room and run `@FireAlarm help` for a command list.

## Where's the code?

The code is [on GitHub](//github.com/SOBotics/FireAlarm/tree/master).  FireAlarm uses two libraries I've helped write: [SwiftChatSE](//github.com/SOBotics/SwiftChatSE), a Swift chatbot framework, and [SwiftStack](//github.com/SOBotics/SwiftStack), an API wrapper [FelixSFD](//stackoverflow.com/users/4687348/felixsfd) and I have been working on.  You may reuse any of the code in your own projects; it's all licensed under MIT.

Comment: FR: don't add a report if the same question has already been cv-pleased

Comment: If that doesn't get implemented: FR: add the `ninja'd` reply command that deletes the report after the fact

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, a `delete` command seems sensible (and more useful). It'll be pretty hard to track all the cv-pls'es, and IMO unnecessary.

Comment: Any plans on bringing this back? cc:@AshishAhuja

Comment: @M-- I don't have any plans for the time being (I'm not sure about Ashish). FireAlarm was my middle school hobby project; my free time is a *lot* more scarce than it was back then, and I have other things I would rather spend it on. I doubt I'll ever pick it up again, since the behavior of Stack Overflow, Inc. over the past couple years has left a sour taste in my mouth about heavily involving myself in the site again.

Comment: @M-- If you're interested in running it yourself, you just need to: **1.** [install Swift](https://swift.org/download), **2.** (if you're on Linux) [install libwebsockets](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets), **3.** clone the GitHub repo and create a `secrets.json` containing `{"email": "<SE account email>", "password": "<SE account password>"}`, and **4.** start the bot with `DEVELOPMENT=<room ID to join> swift run`.

Comment: Oh...!?, good, at least I can post a Comment...!, 125-Rep required to downvote, so you "miss" the '-1', I was going to post a Comment anyway, (I (nearly) always do when I downvote), but "February 8" is timeless=useless, I stopped reading, mention the year, and the OP is from 2017-01-18, so "[20xx-]02-08" doesn't really make any sense... (I didn't read any further..., pity because I'm "probably" an "Advanced User" in Technology/ies you are probably using...)