# Bonfire - dashboard for FireAlarm detecting low-quality questions

Tags: app, questions, posts, closing

[FireAlarm](https://stackapps.com/questions/7183/firealarm-detecting-low-quality-questions-with-machine-learning) is a chatbot detecting low-quality questions. [Bonfire](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/) is a web-dashboard written using Ruby on Rails, made specifically for FireAlarm. Upon low quality post detection, FireAlarm sends all the post data such as detection score and reasons to Bonfire. Bonfire keeps permanent record of these available to the public.

Bonfire was created for a number of reasons, few among them being permanent records of reports, better moderation through custom review queues and filter accuracy statistics.

**What all does Bonfire feature?**

- [Permanent records of posts](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/posts).
- [All posts caught by specific reasons](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/reasons).
- [Two custom review queues](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/review), which allow you to directly close vote on questions after seeing a preview. [Has a publicly available review history](https://bonfire.sobotics.org/review/history), for transparency.

Bonfire will also have a section devoted to statistics gathering in the future.

**I have an issue or a feature request. Whom should I contact?**

You can always make an issue on the Github repository. Also feel free to drop into the [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) to clear up a doubt!

**Where is the source? How can I use it?**

[The source is publicly available on Github](https://github.com/SOBotics/Bonfire). It is licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/SOBotics/Bonfire/blob/master/LICENSE.md).